# Increasing the functionality of my Scrapy spider - Following internal links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created the scrapy spider below and I want to improve its functionality so that I can capture more data.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from TOSpider.items import TOSpiderItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "TOSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://nowtoronto.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        listings = hxs.select("//span[@class='listing-body']")
    items = []
        for listings in listings:
            item = NowTorontoItem()
            item ["eventArtist"] = listings.select("div[@class='List-    Body']/span[@class='List-Name']/text()").extract()
            item ["eventTitle"] = listings.select("div[@class='List-Body']/span[@class='List-Body-Emphasis']/text()").extract()
            item ["eventHolder"] = listings.select("div[@class='List-Body']/span[@class='List-Body-Strong']/text()").extract()
            item ["eventDetails"] = listings.select("div[@class='List-Body']/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Specifically, I want it to be able to follow a link and then capture data on the linked page. If you look at the source code for the site it scrapes from - http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/ -, you will see that each `<div>` that is being scraped also contains an internal link within a `<div>` called `<div class="listing-readmore">`. I would like to follow each internal link so I can then scrape the data from the internal page, specifically the data contained within the `<span>` tags named `<span property="v:location">`, `<span property="v:organization">`, `<span property="v:name">`, `<span property="v:street-address">`, `<span property="v:locality">`, `<span property="v:postal-code">`, `<span property="v:tel">` and `<span property="v:url">` and the `<td>` tags named `<td class="small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD">ADMISSION</td>`, `<td class="small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD">TICKETS AT</td>` and `<td class="small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD">WHEN</td>`.

I have read the Scrapy manual on how to follow internal links but everything I have tried has produced an error. It hasn't seemed to click for me yet and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Note: The items file referenced in the import statement is

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class TOSpiderItem(Item):
    eventArtist = Field()
    eventTitle = Field()
    eventHolder = Field()
    eventDetails = Field()
```

**Edit**

After playing around with the code provided so graciously provided by paul t., I have come up with the following spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from NT.items import NowTorontoItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "NTSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://nowtoronto.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/"]`

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.listing-item0, div.listing-item1")

        for listing in listings:
            item = NowTorontoItem()
            for body in listing.css('span.listing-body > div.List-Body'):
                item ["eventArtist"] = body.css("span.List-Name::text").extract()
                item ["eventTitle"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Emphasis::text").extract()
                item ["eventHolder"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Strong::text").extract()
                item ["eventDetails"] = body.css("::text").extract()

            # instead of returning all items at the end,
            # you can use yield with an item in each iteration
            yield item

            # and you can also yield a Request()
            # so that scrapy enqueues a new page to fetch
            detail_url = listing.select("div.listing-readmore > a::attr(href)")
            if detail_url:
                yield Request(detail_url.extract()[0], callback=self.parse_details)


    def parse_details(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("whenwhereContent")

        for listing in listings:
            item = TOSpiderItem()
            for body in listing.css('td.small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD > td.small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD'):
                item ["eventLocation"] = body.css("span.v:location::text").extract()
                item ["eventOrganization"] = body.css("span.v:organization::text").extract()                      
                item ["eventName"] = body.css("span.v:name::text").extract()  
                item ["eventAddress"] = body.css("span.v:street-address::text").extract()
                item ["eventLocality"] = body.css("span.v:locality::text").extract()                      
                item ["eventPostalCode"] = body.css("span.v:postal-code::text").extract()
                item ["eventPhone"] = body.css("span.v:tel::text").extract()
                item ["eventURL"] = body.css("span.v:url::text").extract()
                item.append(item)
            return item
```

However, when I run it, I receive the error `exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: div.listing-readmore > a::attr<href>`. Can anyone help me out with this? I am not that familiar with the new CSS selectors.

**Edit 2**

I changed `detail_url = listing.select("div.listing-readmore > a::attr(href)")` to `detail_url = listing.css("div.listing-readmore > a::attr(href)")` and I am now receiving the error `yield Request(detail_url.extract()[0], callback=self.parse_details) exceptions.NameError: global name 'Request' is not defined`. Does the Request function need to be imported?

**Edit 3**

I still can't get the second block of code to run. I've attached the entire code block below. Note that I have changed the name of TOSpiderItem to NowTorontoItem. When I run this code, the numbers 1 and 2 will print to screen with each iteration but 3 and 4 will never print, suggesting that the second code block is not running. At this point, it doesn't even seem to be the second big `for` loop that is the problem since it doesn't even have a chance to execute.

```
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from NT.items import NowTorontoItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "NTSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://nowtoronto.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.listing-item0, div.listing-item1")

            for listing in listings:
            item = NowTorontoItem()
            for body in listing.css('span.listing-body > div.List-Body'):
                item ["eventArtist"] = body.css("span.List-Name::text").extract()
                item ["eventTitle"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Emphasis::text").extract()
                item ["eventHolder"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Strong::text").extract()
                item ["eventDetails"] = body.css("::text").extract()
             #for body in listing.css('div.listing-readmore'):
             #  item ["eventURL"] = body.css("a::attr(href)").extract()

            # instead of returning all items at the end,
            # you can use yield with an item in each iteration
            yield item

            # and you can also yield a Request()
            # so that scrapy enqueues a new page to fetch
            detail_url = listing.css("div.listing-readmore")
            print '1'
            if detail_url:
                yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,
                                               detail_url.extract()[0]),
                              callback=self.parse_details)
            print '2'                  


    def parse_details(self, response):

        print '3' 

        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.whenwhereContent")

    print '4' 

        for listing in listings:
            for body in listing.css('td.small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD'):
                item = NowTorontoItem()
                item ["eventLocation"] = body.css("span.v:location::text").extract()
                item ["eventOrganization"] = body.css("span.v:organization::text").extract()                      
                item ["eventName"] = body.css("span.v:name::text").extract()  
                item ["eventAddress"] = body.css("span.v:street-address::text").extract()
                item ["eventLocality"] = body.css("span.v:locality::text").extract()                      
                item ["eventPostalCode"] = body.css("span.v:postal-code::text").extract()
                item ["eventPhone"] = body.css("span.v:tel::text").extract()
                item ["eventURL"] = body.css("span.v:url::text").extract()
                yield item
```

Comment: `item = TOSpiderItem()` must be done inside the loop, just above `item["eventLocation"]`. And instead of `item.append(item)` and `return item`, just do `yield item`

Comment: I've made the changes but it still doesn't seem to be running the second code block. See Edit 3 for details. I know this is proving to be far more involved than it first seemed and I sincerely appreciate the time you've taken to help me out.

Comment: OK. So I didnt notice at first but there is a first problem about `allowed_domains = ["http://nowtoronto.com/"]`. It should be a list of domains, not URLs, so use `allowed_domains = ["nowtoronto.com"]`. For the rest, I added a spider I've tested in my answer. It's not perfect, and some selectors need work still, but you should see more data scraped.

Comment: Thank you. I am testing it out now and it seems like it's almost there. Is there a way I can easily limit the number of results returned so I don't hit the site too hard while I am testing?

Comment: An interesting setting is `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED=True` and you can also set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` to 3 or 4 if you like

Comment: It now seems to be returning only the second code block's data and not the first. If I allow the first `yield item` to run, I get all the data but on different rows, i.e., a single event's data is split among two rows. Any thoughts?

Comment: This thread is getting away from the original question of fetching internal links, and may confuse readers. Please consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like:

```
import urlparse
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from TOSpider.items import TOSpiderItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "TOSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://nowtoronto.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        listings = hxs.select("//div[starts-with(@class, 'listing-item')]")

        for listing in listings:
            item = NowTorontoItem()
            item["eventArtist"] = listing.select("span[@class='listing-body']/div[@class='List-Body']/span[@class='List-Name']/text()").extract()
            item["eventTitle"] = listing.select("span[@class='listing-body']/div[@class='List-Body']/span[@class='List-Body-Emphasis']/text()").extract()
            item["eventHolder"] = listing.select("span[@class='listing-body']/div[@class='List-Body']/span[@class='List-Body-Strong']/text()").extract()
            item["eventDetails"] = listing.select("span[@class='listing-body']/div[@class='List-Body']/text()").extract()

            # instead of returning all items at the end,
            # you can use yield with an item in each iteration
            yield item

            # and you can also yield a Request()
            # so that scrapy enqueues a new page to fetch
            detail_url = listing.select("div[@class='listing-readmore']/a/@href")
            if detail_url:
                yield Request(detail_url.extract()[0], callback=self.parse_details)


    def parse_details(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # and here you parse 
        # <span property="v:location">, 
        # <span property="v:organization">, 
        # <span property="v:name">, 
        # <span property="v:street-address">, 
        # <span property="v:locality">, 
        # <span property="v:postal-code">, 
        # <span property="v:tel"> and <span property="v:url"> ...
        #
        # and return a item
```

Equivalent but using the new CSS selectors:

```
import urlparse
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from TOSpider.items import TOSpiderItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "TOSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://nowtoronto.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.listing-item0, div.listing-item1")

        for listing in listings:
            item = NowTorontoItem()
            for body in listing.css('span.listing-body > div.List-Body'):
                item ["eventArtist"] = body.css("span.List-Name::text").extract()
                item ["eventTitle"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Emphasis::text").extract()
                item ["eventHolder"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Strong::text").extract()
                item ["eventDetails"] = body.css("::text").extract()

            # instead of returning all items at the end,
            # you can use yield with an item in each iteration
            yield item

            # and you can also yield a Request()
            # so that scrapy enqueues a new page to fetch
            detail_url = listing.css("div.listing-readmore > a::attr(href)")
            if detail_url:
                yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,
                                               detail_url.extract()[0]),
                              callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        # and here you parse 
        # <span property="v:location">, 
        # <span property="v:organization">, 
        # <span property="v:name">, 
        # <span property="v:street-address">, 
        # <span property="v:locality">, 
        # <span property="v:postal-code">, 
        # <span property="v:tel"> and <span property="v:url"> ...
        #
        # and return a item
```

---

Edited spider to get OP's started:

```
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
#from NT.items import NowTorontoItem
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class NowTorontoItem(Item):
    eventArtist = Field()
    eventTitle = Field()
    eventHolder = Field()
    eventDetails = Field()

    eventLocation = Field()
    eventOrganization = Field()
    eventName = Field()
    eventAddress = Field()
    eventLocality = Field()
    eventPostalCode = Field()
    eventPhone = Field()
    eventURL = Field()

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "NTSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["nowtoronto.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.listing-item0, div.listing-item1")

        for listing in listings:
            item = NowTorontoItem()
            for body in listing.css('span.listing-body > div.List-Body'):
                item ["eventArtist"] = body.css("span.List-Name::text").extract()
                item ["eventTitle"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Emphasis::text").extract()
                item ["eventHolder"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Strong::text").extract()
                item ["eventDetails"] = body.css("::text").extract()
                #for body in listing.css('div.listing-readmore'):
                #    item ["eventURL"] = body.css("a::attr(href)").extract()

            # instead of returning all items at the end,
            # you can use yield with an item in each iteration
            #yield item

            # and you can also yield a Request()
            # so that scrapy enqueues a new page to fetch
            detail_url = listing.css("div.listing-readmore > a::attr(href)")

            if detail_url:
                yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,
                                               detail_url.extract()[0]),
                              callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        self.log("parse_details: %r" % response.url)
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.whenwhereContent")

        for listing in listings:
            for body in listing.css('td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD'):
                item = NowTorontoItem()
                item ["eventLocation"] = body.css("span[property='v:location']::text").extract()
                item ["eventOrganization"] = body.css("span[property='v:organization'] span[property='v:name']::text").extract()
                item ["eventName"] = body.css("span[property='v:name']::text").extract()
                item ["eventAddress"] = body.css("span[property='v:street-address']::text").extract()
                item ["eventLocality"] = body.css("span[property='v:locality']::text").extract()
                item ["eventPostalCode"] = body.css("span[property='v:postal-code']::text").extract()
                item ["eventPhone"] = body.css("span[property='v:tel']::text").extract()
                item ["eventURL"] = body.css("span[property='v:url']::text").extract()
                yield item
```

Comment: Hm I think `//span[@class='listing-body']` is at same level as the detail links, to it's probably better to use `listings = hxs.select("//div[starts-with(@class, 'listing-item')]")` to select `<div class="listing-item1">` and `<div class="listing-item0">`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this out. I will review it later tonight and see if I can get it working. Just looking at it briefly helped a ton with the logic of the entire process.

Comment: Those new CSS selectors look awesome. I will definitely be trying those out.

Comment: I tried out your code including adding in the details for the second part of the scrape but I seem to be getting an XPath error. Could you possibly take a look at my edit to see what I'm referring to? Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, I don't really understand the > syntax so I'm struggling to diagnose the issue.

Comment: My bad. `listing.select(.....)` should be `listing.xpath(....)` when using XPath expressions and `listing.css(....)` when CSS selectors are used

Comment: I made the change but I am now receiving a different error. Could you possibly take another look? Thanks again.

Comment: you need `from scrapy.http import Request` at the top

Comment: I figured it was something like but I wasn't sure what to import. Thanks.

Comment: That worked but of course, I now have another issue with grabbing the link. I need to append `'http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/'` to the beginning of the URL but it seems I can't simply concatenate a string and a SelectorList object. How can I get this done?

Comment: Thanks. It's now running without errors but it is not grabbing anything from the URLs (only the main listing page). I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that `for body in listing.css('td.small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD > td.small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD')` is not correct so the for loop is being skipped. I don't fully understand the `>` part of the syntax so I was just guessing based on what I saw in your code. I would truly appreciate it if you could explain how that is supposed to work.

Comment: to select `<td class="small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD">` you use this CSS selector syntax: `td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD`. You could omit the `>` in CSS selectors (but this can lead to surprises). I suggest you study CSS selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors . Note that `::text` and `::attr(attrname)` are Scrapy non-standard extensions

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll take a look now.

Comment: I've been playing around with the script and it appears that the second block of code is never run. I've outputted some messages to the screen and everything in the first block definitely runs and nothing in the second block runs. Furthermore, I've tested the syntax for grabbing the URL and it appears to be working in that I can store it in a variable and append it to the item variable. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm very confused. The code `return item` must be running because I can write the results from the first block of code to a CSV file and yet if I try to place a `print` line directly above `return item`, it doesn't print (both in and out of the `for` loop).